# Passing parameter to script from Invoke-AzVMRunCommand

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

I trying to execute the  Invoke-AzVMRunCommand to execute a PS function that accept parameters. The code below shows call to the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand

```
$runcmdparameters=@{
        "VolumeLable"="sdsd";
        "azurelun"="1,3,4"
                    }

Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ServerResourceGroupName -VMName $VMVame -ScriptPath "c:\Configurestorage.ps1" -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -Parameter $runcmdparameters -Verbose
```

The PS Script that I need to execute on the server is

```
function Configure-Storage
     {
          Param(
          [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$VolumeLable,
          [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String[]]$azurelun
          )

#create a storage pool for user databases.
 Out-File "C:\Temp\log.txt" -InputObject $VolumeLable -Append

}

Configure-Storage -VolumeLable $VolumeLable -azurelun $azurelun
```

> The script fail with Cannot bind argument to parameter 'VolumeLable'
>   because it is an empty string.

Microsoft documentation on [Invoke-AzVMRunCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/invoke-azvmruncommand?view=azps-1.2.0) is not very helpful.

How can I pass the parameter to the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do this:

```
Param(
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$VolumeLable,
   [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String[]]$azurelun
)

#create a storage pool for user databases.
Out-File "C:\Temp\log.txt" -InputObject $VolumeLable -Append
```

Because what happens now: your script doesnt really accept parameters, you function does, but you are calling the script, not the function. and then you call the function inside the script. another way of fixing this - add parameters to the script itself

Comment: Thanks. That works like a charm. But a slight problem. The value for $azurelun is the result of 
((get-azvm  -ResourceGroupName $ServerResourceGroupName -Name $VMVame).StorageProfile.DataDisks)|Where-Object {$_.Name -like  $filters[1] }|Select-object -ExpandProperty "LUN"

Comment: But when script receives,  it is outputing as  System.Object[]

Comment: probably because it cannot pass in a complex type. pass it as json, or better just parse disks from inside the vm, easier\more reliable

Comment: That make sense. Our Azure subscription has 2fa enables. Is there a way to pass the credentials to the  Invoke-AzVMRuncommand.

Comment: you mean MFA? no, you can silently auth with MFA, but you can use [MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview), so you dont really need to auth from inside VMs, but that's different question altogether

Comment: Yes MFA. Curious to learn MSI and silent authentication.. please can you share some articles..

Comment: create a new question mate :)