# Passing parameters to PowerShell Script from Invoke-AzVMRunCommand

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand in PowerShell and pass parameters to the script that needs to be executed.

See code below:

```
$params=@{
    "path" = "C:\Users\";
    "name" = "TEST"
}


Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $rg `
                      -VMName $vm_name `
                      -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' `
                      -ScriptPath $script_path `
                      -Parameter $params
```

Script on the server I want to execute with the parameters:

```
Param(
    [string]$path,
    [string]$name
)

MKdir -Path $path -Name $name
```

I get no error after executing the above scripts. Output:

```
Value     : {Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.InstanceViewStatus, 
            Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.InstanceViewStatus}
Name      : 
StartTime : 
EndTime   : 
Status    : Succeeded
Error     : 
Output    : 
Capacity  : 0
Count     : 0
Item      :
```

The script does not produce the expected output: Creating a folder named TEST under C:\Users. No folder is being created.

If I execute the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand on the same script with hardcoded arguments like so:

```
MKdir -Path "C:\Users\" -Name "TEST"
```

it does work and the folder gets created.

Why is this not working by passing the paramaters as stated above?

Took these resources into consideration, but it did not help:
[Passing parameter to script from Invoke-AzVMRunCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54479813/passing-parameter-to-script-from-invoke-azvmruncommand)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command#powershell

**Solution:**

Changed:

```
$params=@{
    "path" = "C:\Users\"; # <- Removed final backslash here.
    "name" = "TEST"
}


Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $rg `
                      -VMName $vm_name `
                      -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' `
                      -ScriptPath $script_path `
                      -Parameter $params
```

to:

```
$params=@{
    "path" = "C:\Users";
    "name" = "TEST"
}


Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $rg `
                      -VMName $vm_name `
                      -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' `
                      -ScriptPath $script_path `
                      -Parameter $params
```

Removing the final backslash on the path parameter made this working...

Comment: Ok.  So could you try getting rid of the ";" when you define your parameters in the hash table?  The ";" is only needed if all of the properties are declared on the same line.  If you have new lines separating the different properties, the ";" should not be there.  See if that helps first.

Comment: Also, again, may or may not be an issue, but I have noticed that in rare cases (like when using the sharepoint online pnp powershell cmdlets) were case is important.  When you define the parameters in the hashtable, can you try making sure that the property name is the exact same as the parameter defined in the script (Meaning change name to Name and path to Path)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, both recommendations did not work. Same result, no folder is being created.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that.  That being the case, I would recommend posting about your issue in the issues section of the azure powershell module github page:   https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell

Comment: @WilliamHiggs I posted my solution above if you are curious. Removing the final backslash on the path parameter made it working... FYI: I tried the working script with semicolon (;) and without on the properties. It made no difference, both worked. Just to let you know.